# Symfony form ChoiceType with only values

Tags: symfony, drop-down-menu, symfony-forms

The [Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html) says that you should use the use ChoiceType like this :

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;

$builder->add('isAttending', ChoiceType::class, array(
    'choices'  => array(
        'Maybe' => null,
        'Yes' => true,
        'No' => false,
    ),
));
```

However, since my values are simple enough to act like keys, I would like to do something like this :

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;

$builder->add('titre', ChoiceType::class, array(
    'choice_value'  => array(
        'Pr', 'Dr', 'Mr', 'Mrs'
    ),
))
```

How can I achieve this ?

If I cannot, what is the good reason behind ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try create same key/value array with [array_combine](http://php.net/array-combine):

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;

$choices = array('Pr', 'Dr', 'Mr', 'Mrs');

$builder->add('isAttending', ChoiceType::class, array(
    'choices'  => array_combine($choices, $choices),
));
```

Comment: Great ! I was looking to a more symfony-ish way to do it but this works just fine :-)

Answer (score 1):

[A Symfony-ish way](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choice-label):

```
$builder->add('isAttending', ChoiceType::class, array(
    'choices' => array('Pr', 'Dr', 'Mr', 'Mrs'),
    'choice_label' => function ($value) { return $value; },
));
```